# How to load files to local file system with vibed?

Tags: d, vibed

I need to send data from web-browser to local FS. For sending data I am using Vue-JS [component](https://github.com/james2doyle/vue-file-upload-component)

```html
<file-upload class="my-file-uploader" name="myFile" id="myCustomId" action="/upload" multiple>Inside Slot Text</file-upload>
```

My server side based on vibed. But I can't find example how to save binary data to local FS.

```d
router.any("/upload", &upload);    
...
void upload(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{

}
```

It's seems that I should use [HTTPServerRequest](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.http.server/HTTPServerRequest.files).files But I can't understand how to use it. User upload takes is multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a lot of examples within the Vibe.d [Github repository](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/tree/master/examples).

For example there's a small [uploader](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/blob/master/examples/uploader/source/app.d).

```d
router.post("/upload", &uploadFile);

...   

void uploadFile(scope HTTPServerRequest req, scope HTTPServerResponse res)
{
    auto pf = "file" in req.files;
    enforce(pf !is null, "No file uploaded!");
    try moveFile(pf.tempPath, Path(".") ~ pf.filename);
    catch (Exception e) {
        logWarn("Failed to move file to destination folder: %s", e.msg);
        logInfo("Performing copy+delete instead.");
        copyFile(pf.tempPath, Path(".") ~ pf.filename);
    }

    res.writeBody("File uploaded!", "text/plain");
}
```

I don't know much about Vue.js, but [it seems](https://github.com/james2doyle/vue-file-upload-component/blob/master/vue.file-upload.js#L49) they use `file` too.